# facebook opengraph meta tags do not run my video remotely properly

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

I have added facebook meta tags to enable my website to run its video remotely from facebook.
When I add the [URL](http://videoof.co.uk/true-blood-true-blood-for-the-holidays.html) on facebook, it shows the thumbnail properly but does not run the video.

Whats the problem?

Meta tags are as below:

```
 <meta property="fb:app_id" content="182061505193038">
 <meta property="og:url" content="http://videoof.co.uk/true-blood-true-blood-for-the-holidays.html>">
 <meta property="og:title" content="  True Blood: True Blood for the Holidays">
 <meta property="og:type" content="video">
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/p91VTAFsBoc/0.jpg">
 <meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p91VTAFsBoc&feature=youtube_gdata_player">
 <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
 <meta property="og:video:width" content="396">
 <meta property="og:video:height" content="297">
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="Videoof">
```

and this is my debugged URL : [Debug URl](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://videoof.co.uk/true-blood-true-blood-for-the-holidays.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me: https://skitch.com/sicross/gm8tr/4-facebook

Your page runs through the debugger correctly, and when shared, results in a video alongside your stream story.